# Bootstrap: Set table column width for small devices

Tags: html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, angular-ui-bootstrap

How do I set a column width of a table for smaller devices? I am using boostrap3.

Here is my code:

```
      <div class="table-responsive" style="overflow: auto; height:350px;">
        <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Contact</th>
              <th>Message</th>
              <th class="hidden-xs hidden-sm">Time</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>

          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="tr-class">Contact Name</h4><i><small>Address</small></i></td>
              <td class="tr-class ltdmsgcls" >Sample test message. Its a message to test on smaller devices. Need to find out.</td>
              <td class="tr-class hidden-xs hidden-sm">timestamp</td>
              <td><button>&times;</button></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

CSS:

```
  @media (max-width: 768px) {
      .ltdmsgcls {
          table-layout: fixed;
          word-wrap: normal|break-word|initial|inherit;
              width: 100px;
      }
  }
```

With this I am not able to decrease the width of the column of Message. I see a horizontal scroll bar for smaller devices. How do I set width of Message column so that it is visible and column data is wrapped on smaller devices (of different sizes). As of now larger devices shows this in proper way.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware of media queries, your media query should be :

```
@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
      .ltdmsgcls {
          table-layout: fixed;
          word-wrap: normal|break-word|initial|inherit;
              width: 100px;
      }
}
```

Instead of what you had.

Comment: This is getting applied only for width equal to 768px and not less than width 768px.

Answer (score 0):

To someone who come across same issue. Here is what I tried and worked.

```
    @media 
    only screen and (max-width: 767px),
    (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {
        .table-responsive > .table > tbody > tr > td {
            white-space: inherit;
        }
     }
```